# Read file in binary and output in hex std::cin to std::cout

Tags: c++

I was trying to achieve this using this code:

```
char c;
while (std::cin >> c)
  std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<uint32_t>(c);
```

but it looks like it gets messed up reading in nulls (all nulls are removed from my file).  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input stream operator typically requires a separator, you should read a buffer from the file, something like shown here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/, then iterate over the contents and print out, you may also want to use `showbase` to make the hex output prettier...

EDIT: try something like this:

```
char c;
while(std::cin.get(c))
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you :), but unfortunately I need to be able to use this as part of a pipe chain in a bash shell so I need it to take a file through stdin and print the conversion to stdout.  Any ideas for that?

Comment: @w00te: `read` is a member function of `istream`, which is a base class of the type of `std::cin`. Just don't copy the parts of that example code that open the file, and then since you can't seek you'll have to pick a buffer size out of thin air (or performance testing), and read/write blocks in a loop until end of stream.

Comment: Thanks again, the file is opened as binary.  Do I have to do something similar to let the program know the cin stream is reading binary in my case?